# Using Zorns Lemma, does my arguement hold?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

So this is homework. I do want to complete it myself but am just unsure if my argument actually holds or if I have even structured it correctly. So would just like to know if my structure is correct and if not why it would fail. I've only got an outline. I'll give question I was given and then the outline of the argument I'm making.

"Let A & B be any two sets. Let X be the collection of functions that map subsets of A 1-1 onto a subset of B.  Define a partial order on X and use Zorn's Lemma to show that there is a function that maps A 1-1 into B OR part of A onto B"

So I define a partial order $(X, \le) $ such that f{A_1} \le f{A_2} means the domain of $A_1 \subseteq A_2$.  Is this the correct partial order to use? How about the size of the codomain instead?  Then I let S be the set of all totally ordered subsets of X where each set is ordered by amount of elements mapped and their order as f is bijective it must be increasing. Therefore each one of these subsets has an upper bound in A. And by Zorn's lemma there is a maximal element in the chain of these upper bounds. 
So if this upperbound is in one of the A_i then this A_i includes all the other A and as f maps 1-1 and onto subsets of B then this shows all of A is mapped 1-1 into B.
other case is that this upperbound is not in any of the A_i but the largest A_i to which it is an upper bound to maps 1-1 onto B as this is what f does and it must be all of B as this upperbound in A has no where to map to without negating injectivity of the function f.

Is this argument ok? have I structured it correctly? The partial order, what I've inferred from this order and the properties of the function?

Any constructive criticism is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since the subject is Zorn, perhaps you'd appreciate nonconstructive criticism too :-)

Comment: I laughed so I will say thank you to that. But has anyone got some criticism about my argument?

Comment: Your "partial order" is not really a partial order, because it's not antisymmetric. It is possible for two functions $f_1,f_2$ to have the same domain, yet be different functions. But your $\leq$-relation will then yield $f_1 \leq f_2$ and $f_2 \leq f_1$, which would need to imply $f_1 = f_2$ if $\leq$ truely were a PO.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148928/proof-of-comparability-theorem-using-zorn-lemma

Comment: yea I see what you mean, I was a bit unsure about what PO to use. So would using the range of f ie the subsets of B that f maps subsets of A to also fail to define a proper partial order? just cant see what other type of order besides size would work given such limited info on the sets . . . also as it would allow me to put bounds on the subsets.

Comment: Don't forget that a function is also a set. Maybe that gives you an idea for a partial order you can use.

Comment: You need to take the *behaviour* of the function into account. A good choice for the PO would be to interpret $f$ as a subset of $A \times B$, i.e. as the set of pairs $(a,f(a))$. $f_1 \leq f_2$ then means that $f_2$ *extends* $f_1$, i.e. that whenever $a$ lies in the domain of $f_1$, then $f_2(a) = f_1(a)$.

Comment: I thought I was taking the behaviour of the function into account as because its 1-1 and onto then its bijective and increasing. Also it maps subsets of A so by using domain as PO then each function that maps larger domain would include function that maps smaller. But I do see how this does not satisfy definition of PO. So if I use the PO you've described and define a total order on the subsets will this order them by their domain size? so as its always increasing and onto , successive functions will be "larger" in a sense?

Comment: @user24907: What **fgp** means is that your order takes into account only the domain of the function, not what it actually ‘does to’ that domain. If you simply consider $X$ a subset of $\wp(A\times B)$ partially ordered by $\subseteq$ (which is **fgp**’s suggestion), then you know that you have a partial order. The next step is to show that if $C$ is a chain in this partial order, then $\bigcup C\in X$, i.e., $\bigcup C$ is a partial function from $A$ to $B$. And yes, if $f,g\in X$, and $f\subseteq g$, then $\operatorname{dom}f\subseteq\operatorname{dom}g$ automatically.

Comment: I see this works as a partial order but what I don't see is what the upperbounds that form this chain will be.If X is (A\times B) then subsets are (a,f(a)) so upperbounds are of this form too or are they a function? haven't really learned to think of functions as sets themselves. . . as the question suggests this maximal element assured by the lemma either maps A 1-1 into B OR maps part of A 1-1 onto B this suggests the maximal element will be a function that must exhaust all of A or B so it is of form ( a, f(a)) ?

Comment: @user24907: I don’t know what you mean by ‘upperbounds that form this chain’: we aren’t making a chain of upper bounds. We simply need to show that each chain **has** an upper bound, and in my comment I told you what to use: if $C$ is a chain in $X$, $\bigcup C$ is in fact an upper bound of $C$ in $X$, though of course you have to prove this. $X$ is **not** $A\times B$; it’s $$\{f\subseteq A\times B:f\text{ is a partial function}\}\;.$$ Elements of $X$ are **subsets** of $A\times B$, not **elements** of $A\times B$.